# Relative path issue angular js application when it serve from in nginx proxy pass

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx

I have an angular js application which is serving from a node server which is running a at locahost:8050. It's running fine when I hit localhost:8050. But I want that request will come to localhost:8050 through a proxy, so I have set up nginx like below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ingl.sorc.com;
    location /portal/gen/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8050;    
        }
}
```

and also make 127.0.0.1 ingl.sorc.com entry to the etc hosts file.

So when I am hitting ingl.sorc.com/portal/gen/ this URL it shows a blank page. It shows blank page because it try to get css and js file from "http://ingl.sorc.com/styles/vendor.a31e3c2d.css" and "http://ingl.sorc.com/styles/vendor.st34hj.js", those file eventually not exists in the particular path.

I am using grunt to build angular application. After build the application in index.html css and js are added to the page using relative path. For example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.46a5c195.css">
<script src="scripts/vendor.7925e705.js"></script>
```

Please help me. I have no idea how can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a valid entry for styles. Try something like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ingl.sorc.com;
    location /portal/gen/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8050;    
    }
    location /styles/ {
        # you'll have to find the right path 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8050/styles; 
    }    

}
```